# Trying to check whether a list contains an item in bash/ unix without validating substrings but including the first and last items

Tags: shell-script

This is my first time posting here so any feedback is very welcome should I be doing something wrong! I'm very new to shell scripting and am trying to write a function that checks whether an item is in a list. In this case I'm checking whether a given argument correspond to an existing user on the system. I really want to avoid false positives by making sure the item is surrounded by spaces but that obviously excludes the first and last item in the list. I figured maybe I could add spaces to the start and end of the list but I can't figure out how to do this. Any tips or pointers are very welcome! My code so far comes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063228/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-exists-in-a-list-in-bash). It looks like this:

-->This is the list of existing users

```
users=$(getent passwd {1000..60000} | awk -F ':' '{print $1}')
```

-->Function to check whether the given command line argument is in existing users

```
contains(){
   [[ $1 =~ (^|[[:space:]])"$2"($|[[:space:]]) ]] && return 0 || return 1
}
```

Where $1 is the list of users obtained with getent from passwd file (see above) and $2 is the given (command line) argument I'm trying to validate.

Just as information: for testing purposes I've been trying out the contains function with a list (1 2 3 4). It works if I check this against 2 and 3, but not for 1 and 4.

Comment: To test whether a username is valid on the system, use the return status of `getent passwd "$username" >/dev/null` instead.  Not posting that as an answer, as a proper answer should probably reference the code that you are using.  You also seem to be missing `]]` before `&&`, and you should mention what the values `$1` and `$2` looks like.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've clarified my question and added some context. Also fixed the brackets I forgot to type.

Comment: To visualize the input, can you post that formatted list or a portion of it, plus an example of the given argument? Give dummy users instead of the real ones if you want.

Comment: I've added some information, but I can change the formatting of the list so if I can get this to work for the simple test example I've added I'll be helped greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the custom function below. It accepts a list where each item is on a separate line. See usage.

```
contains(){ printf "%s\n" "$1"|grep '^'"$2"'$' > /dev/null; }
```

The return code is that of the grep command:

- 0 - if the item was found in the list (full line match, case sensitive)
- 1 - if the item was not found in the list
- 2 or higher - if an error occurred (the error message will be printed)

Modifications that you might need to do on the above function to make it work as you want:

- don't print anything, not even a possible error message: `&> /dev/null`
- print everything (the item if present in the list, a possible error message): remove `> /dev/null`
- print only if the item is present in the list, don't print a possible error message: `2> /dev/null`
- force the function to return only 0 or 1: `&& return 0 || return 1;`

**Usage:**

```
list="$(getent passwd {1000..60000}|cut -f1 -d:)"
item="USER_NAME_HERE"
#or
list="$(printf "%s\n" {1..4})"
item="1"
#then
contains "$list" "$item"
#to see the return code
echo $?
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find a way that works! Much obliged :)

Comment: @BlueUmbrella51 You welcome. Have a look also on Jim L.'s answer, as `grep -Fx "$2"` is much better than `grep '^'"$2"'$'`. If you want to be informed of errors, don't use `grep -q`. All the best.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the man! I upvoted both your answers but since I have no reputation it isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
users="$(getent passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}')"

contains(){
   grep -qFx "$2" <<< "$1"
}
```

Test this with something like:

```
if contains "$users" "jim"; then
  echo jim is a user
else
  echo jim is not a user
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated!